# How to find length of the li when the parent div is 1000%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am actually working on a slider and I want to find the width of the li element.

```
<div class="slider"><div class="touch-slider-viewport">
<ul style="width: 1000%; transition: 0.5s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <li>

    <div>
        <img src="images/01.jpg">
        <p>Something Something </p>
    </div>

    </li>
   </ul>
```

I have tried using `$('li').width()` it gives me some different width when I pass it through my js but when i try it in console it gives me the correct width of the li element. I think it's because of the 1000% width i have given for the parent element. Any idea how can i get the width of the li?

CSS:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .slider li{
    width:2.38%;
}

}
@media (min-width: 504px) and (max-width: 1023px)  {
.slider li{
    width:3.3%;
}
}
@media all and (max-width: 503px) {
.slider li{
    width:4.6%;
}
}

.slider li{
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-right:8px;

}
```

Comment: try `parseFloat($('li').css('width'))`. jQuery's `width()` method in some cases may return faulty or inconsistent results.

Comment: depends when you check it....show full code. Are images loaded when you check? Are elements visible also? Issue isn't clear without full details

Comment: you need to call the javascript AFTER the document is ready to avoid any inconsistencies... also is it 1000px or 1000% ? You can also check the width of the `li` using the browser developer tools (example in Chrome: http://puu.sh/keUyo/3c7690a95d.png)

Comment: @Aziz Sorry i was just experimenting with 1000px i have edited it now. And yes i can see the width but i need the width in a variable. When i do it via JS its giving me the wrong width to be precise it's giving me the value width/10. I am confused why is it doing this thing.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your help. It was my silly mistake of declaring the width after i was making the call. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I actually think using `width()` should be fine. I don't think that's the problem (using `width()` is better than `innerWidth()`, so stick with it).

If you could provide more details about when you receive the wrong width (when you 'pass it through your js') we may be able to be of more help, but it could be a loading issue (if the page hasn't fully rendered and you try to get the width of an element, you may get an inaccurate result).

If the console returns the correct width, then I don't think it's the `width()` function that's at fault.

---

Try using `innerWidth()`.

`$('li').innerWidth()`

http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It was my silly mistake of declaring the width after i was making the call. It's fixed now.

Comment: @user1819887 -  No problem, I didn't think it would have been the use of `width` that was the problem. Glad you got it sorted.